# How can we change jenkins global variable value from pipeline job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to change defined global variable "foo = false" to value "true" at run-time for the buildpipeline. that chnage value should be available for that build scoop only.

Comment: changes on global variable should be available to the whole pipeline. To archive your purpose, why assign global value to a block scope variable ,then change the block scope variable.  Please share your pipeline code

Answer (score 0):

1) For Declarative Pipeline:

```
def global_var= false

pipeline {
  stages {
    stage('foo') {
      steps {
        script {
          def block_var = global_var
          ...
          block_var = true
        }
        // or
        ...
        block_var = true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2) For Scripted Pipeline:

```
def global_var= false

node() {

  stage('foo') {
    def block_var = global_var
    ...
    block_var = true
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yong for your input. there is little change in workflow and what i need here in query. I have to use this global_var changed value in our further process. other defined variable will not work for me. I am calling an another msbuild proj file from the pipeline and value of newly defined var will not travel to proj file. only global_var can travel.

Comment: Actually, it's a lot. let me share you my build workflow that would probably help you to understand more;
We have two Jenkins jobs and three build files inside the repo to compile and package the build. 1st job calls 2nd and 2nd calls build files (.proj files)....
MAIN_JOB -> SUBMAIN_JOB -> Jenkinsbuild.proj => A.proj OR B.proj 
I have to manage the calling of A.proj and B.proj from the Jenkinsbuild.proj build file.

Comment: The real requirement is, two separate builds require from the one repo. Our build scripts are generic for all other builds so we can't change thoroughly. 
only we can change the MAIN_JOB and *.proj files to manage the workflow.

Comment: What I was planning to manage the scenario.
- Create Jenkin global variable (Global_var) - it will travel throughout all jobs and *.proj files
- In Jenkinsbuild.proj, if Global_var=true then A.proj will call and if Global_var=false then B.proj
- So for the true value, Need to change it from my MAIN job itself. 
- Also SUBMAIN_JOB is a generic job that calls from other projects MAIN jobs too. so we can't use it for any modification
I hope I am able to describe my real query.

Comment: let me summarize the current workflow for you and other projects.

`each project's MAIN_JOB -> common SUBMAIN_JOB -> Jenkinsbuild.proj -> project's proj`

So each project's MAIN_JOB will tell SUBMAIN_JOB should use which .proj of each project to build each project.  Is correct?

Comment: If my summary above is correct and all projects comply with the workflow in my summary above.  Why you can't make the common `SUBMAIN_JOB` to have a parameter to accept the proj file name of each project, then each project's `Main_JOB` specify the proj file name when invoke `SUBMAIN_JOB`

Comment: It really sounds good if I will have to make a entire new workflow but the problem is we can't modify the current workflow as it associates with many projects and their builds. Jenkinsbuild.proj is again a generic kind of proj file reside in each project repos. Groovy pipeline has a hard-coded value to call jenkinsbuild.proj from the each project.